# GOLD Parser : ANSI-C grammar not actually parsing ANSI-C?

Tags: grammar, gold-parser

I'm trying to test the ANSI-C grammar provided on the GOLD Parser website.
I can't seem to even completly parse the smallest of the C file.

Example:

```
int test_inc1(void)
{
  int t;
  t = 2 + 2;
  return 0;
}
```

It find int as a type, then test_inc1 as an Id, then parantheses correctly but after the second ), it is expecting a ; instead of a {. So it throws a syntax error.
I'm very new into all this grammar funkyness. I'd simply like to parse my code into an AST :(

Comment: For reference this is the ANSI-C grammar I'm using from the GOLD website. I'm testing it inside the GOLD Parser Builder 4.1.1 : http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/grammars/files/C-ANSI.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the grammar, the first line could be a `<Func Proto>`, if it was terminated by a semicolon:

```
<Func Proto> ::= <Func ID> '(' <Types>  ')' ';'
               | <Func ID> '(' <Params> ')' ';'
               | <Func ID> '(' ')' ';'
```

For parsing a function declaration, this production from the quoted grammar should have matched the part between the parentheses:

```
<Param>      ::= const <Type> ID
               |       <Type> ID
```

`void` was OK for the `<Type>`, but the `ID` that the grammar asks for just is not there.

But the grammar also contains this hint:

```
! Note: This is an ad hoc version of the language. If there are any flaws, 
! please visit the contact page and tell me.
```

so it should probably not be taken too seriously.